# How to receive event in JS from Java RestApi Spring 3 IE11?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, events, http2

The application in based on Spring 3 for backend and JSP for views and HTML/JS for front.

I have a Rest client that can be called by others applications.

How can i receive in my JS code, when i receive a request on my Rest client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I'd say you need things like Server Push or WebSockets. But those didn't exist yet in Spring 3

HTTP/2 Server Push is only introduces recently in Spring 5: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-push.

And WebSockets where in Spring 4: https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

If you're stuck with Spring 3, I would write a javascript method that does polling, i.e. every few seconds call an Ajax API to see if there are updates that need to be processed.

A more advanced implementation of this idea is done in the ActiveMQ Ajax client: https://activemq.apache.org/ajax .

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I will do an upgrade to Spring 4.2 then use SSE (Server Sent Event) because i just nedd an unidirectional communication from Server to Client. After doing some research SSE and Websockets are almost the same at a performence level. And Spring Websockets requires changing protocol from HTTP to another protocol, then if connection is lost SSE tries to reconnect, but not Websockets where you have to handle reconection yourself.

Comment: SSE is a better alternative for WebSockets if you only need Push Events. One minor issue though: unlike WebSockets it's not supported in Internet Explorer: https://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource

Comment: Currently i only need to push from Server. the js object EventSource is not supported by IE11 but a pollyfil exists. i have asked a question about my use case using SSE, which i will eventually use if it's really realtime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60976881/is-sse-server-sent-event-really-realtime-in-case-there-is-many-suscribers